# How to solve a system of 2 equations in this form

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Equation1 => $Dxy-Zx+Fx^2+Gy^2-Hy+K=0$

Equation2 => $Mxy-Nx+Ox^2+Py^2-Qy+R=0$

These equations when solve will give at most 4 points of Intersection
But how to solve these two equations. 
The above equations when solved will give at most 4 roots

**Note: here Capital Letters are all constant. I need to find the roots.**

Comment: I use the method of "resultants", which is best done with a computer algebra system (Maple, Mathematica) because the intermediate expressions can get pretty involved (especially when using symbolic constants).

Comment: A "by hand" approach would be something like this: Eliminate $y^2$ from the equations (compute $P E_1 - G E_2)$. This gives you a polynomial equation in which the highest power of $y$ is $1$; solve that polynomial for $y$, and substitute the solution into either original equation (note that you'll be squaring a large polynomial as part of the process), and you'll have a quartic polynomial in $x$. From there ... well ... quartics aren't easy to solve symbolically ---check the web--- but, once you have your $x$ values, you can substitute them into the earlier $y$ formula, and you're done!

Comment: This may also help you get started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Intersecting_two_conics

Comment: This is a spin-off from [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/425366/35416). Slightly different formulation for the conics, but essentially the same question, so you might even call it a duplicate. Note that you can solve this problem using only cubic equations, not quartic ones. See [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/425412/35416) for details.