# Conjugate Diameters of the Ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[image: A]

I understand that the blue and red lines are conjugate diameters; but can $GG'$ and $HH'$ be conjugate diameters, in the blue ellipse below? (G' and H' are symmetry points of G, H, by M.)

ABCD is a parallelogram and the blue ellipse is inscribed in ABCD, where each tangent points divide each segment by m : n internally.

[image]

Comment: I answered below, but if you have problems understanding [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4282941/inellipse-area-conjecture-and-siebeck-marden-theorem/4283296#4283296) you'd better ask commenting below that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they are conjugate diameters. There's [a theorem](https://books.google.it/books?id=UlrmKjIjrzQC&pg=PA78&lpg=PA78&dq=theorem%20midpoints%20chords%20ellipse%20conjugate&source=bl&ots=nfJKrHY_5w&sig=ACfU3U33h-OMBTWBUT1e4TlHXVaBe_8CbQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJr-WHmerzAhUjPewKHfvADn4Q6AF6BAgeEAM#v=onepage&q=theorem%20midpoints%20chords%20ellipse%20conjugate&f=false) stating that all midpoints of chords parallel to a diameter of an ellipse lie on the conjugate diameter. $PQ$ is parallel to $MH$ by the intercept theorem, and $N$ is the midpoint of $PQ$ by triangle similarity. Hence the diameter conjugate to $HH'$ lies on line $MN$.

Comment: @Vue My result is exactly the same.