# Determine angular coordinate of contact point between a rotated ellipse and its tangent

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

$\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}$I tried to illustrate the problem in the picture below. An ellipse is rotated by the angle $\alpha$. Since the distance $L$ is given, the tangent to the ellipse can be determined. The angular coordinate $\beta$ is used to describe the tangent point. $\beta$ is measured from the the body-fixed $x$-axis of the ellipse.

[image: picture]

For further calculations I want to determine $\frac{d\beta}{d\alpha}$. Therefore I tried to calculate $\beta = f(\alpha)$ or at least $\cos(\beta) = f(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\beta) = f(\alpha)$.

My approach is to solve the following equation $-y \frac{dx}{d \beta}+x \frac{dy}{d \beta}=0$, where $x = L + r\cos(\beta+\alpha)$ and $y = r \sin(\beta+\alpha)$. $(x,y)$ is the tangent point. The equation follows from the scalar product of $(\frac{dx}{d \beta},\frac{dy}{d \beta})$ and the vector between $0$ and $(x,y)$ rotated by $90°$. I simplified the equation using Mathematica to:
$$
(-1 + \eps^2) L \cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta) - b \sqrt{1 - \eps^2 \cos(\beta)^2} + L \sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta) = 0,
$$
where $\eps$ is the numerical eccentricity of the ellipse.

However, the solution Mathematica provides to this equation is not practical, since I have to do a case distinction. I feel like that my approach uses too much calculus and a different approach would simplify the solution.

Summarizing: What is $\beta = f(\alpha)$, when the parameters $a$ and $b$ of the ellipse are given?

Comment: Your equation cannot be right: for $\epsilon=1$ it gives $\alpha=0$, while the right result should be $\sin\beta=b/L$.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake. The + before the square root has to be a minus. However, for $\epsilon = 1$ and $\alpha = 0$, the result is $cos(\beta) = -\frac{b}{L}$, isn't it? $sin(\beta) = \frac{b}{L}$ would only be right, if $\beta$ is measured from the left-hand side.

Comment: Yes, of course: I had taken the wrong $\beta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made an error somewhere, because I used exactly the same method but came up with a different result:
$$
\cos\beta={ac(\alpha)\over\sqrt{a^2c^2(\alpha)+b^2s^2(\alpha)}},
\quad
\sin\beta={bs(\alpha)\over\sqrt{a^2c^2(\alpha)+b^2s^2(\alpha)}}.
$$
where:
$$
c(\alpha)=\frac{a \sin\alpha 
\sqrt{a^2 \sin ^2\alpha+b^2 \cos ^2\alpha -{a^2 b^2/L^2}}
-{a b^2 \cos\alpha}/{L}}{a^2 \sin ^2\alpha +b^2 \cos ^2\alpha}
$$
and
$$
s(\alpha)=\frac{b \cos\alpha 
\sqrt{a^2 \sin ^2\alpha+b^2 \cos ^2\alpha -{a^2 b^2/L^2}}
+{a^2 b \sin\alpha}/{L}}{a^2 \sin ^2\alpha+b^2\cos^2\alpha}.
$$
To get there, I started with parametric equations for a point on the ellipse:
$$
\tag{1}
r\cos\beta=a\cos t,\quad r\sin\beta=b\sin t,
$$
and the corresponding cartesian equations:
$$
x=r\cos(\alpha+\beta)=a\cos\alpha\cos t-b\sin\alpha\sin t,\\
y=r\sin(\alpha+\beta)=a\sin\alpha\cos t+b\cos\alpha\sin t.
$$
Imposing the scalar product between $(L+x, y)$ and $(\dot y,-\dot x)$ to vanish (dot indicates derivative with respect to $t$) one gets the simple equation
$$
b\cos\alpha\cos t-a\sin\alpha\sin t =-{ab\over L},
$$
which can be solved for $\cos t$ and $\sin t$. Then we can express $\cos\beta$ and $\sin\beta$ in terms of $t$, using $(1)$, and substitute there the solutions thus found:
$$
\cos\beta={a\cos t\over\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}},
\quad
\sin\beta={b\sin t\over\sqrt{a^2\cos^2t+b^2\sin^2t}}.
$$
As a check, I plotted $\beta$, taken from the formula for $\cos\beta$, as a function of $\alpha$ (for $a=2$, $b=1$, $L=5$), and then with GeoGebra made the same plot as computed by the software itself (see picture). The two graphs turn out to be identical.

[image]

EDIT.

Notice that in GeoGebra (and in my formula, due to the presence of $\arccos$) I forced $0\le\beta\le\pi$. If $\alpha_0$ is the point where $\beta=0$, for $\alpha>\alpha_0$ point $H$ in the diagram is to the right of $B$, so it could be advisable to allow $\beta<0$ there.

If you want to do that, you simply have to replace $\beta$ as given by formula above with $-\beta$ for all $\alpha_0<\alpha<\alpha_\pi$, where $\alpha_\pi$ is the point where $\beta=\pi$. To ensure continuity you should also substitute $\beta$ with $\beta-2\pi$ for $\alpha>\alpha_\pi$. In doing so, kinks at $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_\pi$ do disappear and the curve turns out to be smooth.

Comment: Could you show some steps on how to get to your equation for $cos \beta$. I tried it, using $sin \beta = \sqrt{1-cos^2 \beta}$, but that wasn't successfull.

Comment: I will gladly do, but before doing that I would like to know the expression you used for $r$, because you didn't explicitly write it.

Comment: I used $r = \frac{b}{\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2 cos^2 \beta}}$. You probably used $r=\frac{ab}{ \sqrt{a^2 sin^2\beta + b^2 cos^2 \beta}}$. Using that expression I get: $0 = L(b^2 cos \alpha sin \alpha -a^2 sin \alpha sin \beta)+ab \sqrt{b^2 cos^2 \beta +a^2 sin^2 \beta}$

Comment: Yes, I used that. I also noticed an error in my EDIT: I'll correct it.

Comment: There is an error my comment above. It is supposed to be: $0 = L(a^2 sin \alpha sin\beta -b^2 cos \alpha cos \beta) +ab \sqrt{ a^2 sin^2 \beta + b^2 cos^2 \beta}$

Comment: I updated my answer to explain computation details.

Comment: At $y = ....$ the - between the terms has to be a +. It's probably just a typo since the calculations below are correct. However, I am not able to edit it.

Comment: Corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have an ellipse $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ and you want to find points of tangent to the origin.  The tangent line is generally $y=mx$.  Eliminating $y$ between these two equations resulrs in the following quadratic equation for $x$:

$(Cm^2+Bm+A)x^2+(Em+D)x+F=0$

The condition for tangent is that this should have a double root for $x$ meaning the discriminant of the quadratic equation should be zero.  This leads to a quadratic equation for $m$:

$(E^2-4CF)m^2+(2DE-4BF)m+(D^2-4AF)=0$

Note that if $E^2=4CF$ one root for $m$ goes to infinity meaning one tangent line is the $y$ axis.  Otherwise, in general there are two roots for $m$ from which the tangent lines can be determined, provided that $A, C, F$ all have the same sign.

Comment: Would one tangent go to the upper part of the ellipse and the other tangent to the lower part?

Comment: If the ellipse is centered on the $x$-axis, you could say that.  Such a scenario implies $m=0$ gives two roots for $x$ so the tangents must straddle the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to me that it might be easier to rotate the point instead of the ellipse. Let the ellipse be in standard position with half-axis lengths $a$ and $b$, and let $P=(L\cos\theta,L\sin\theta)$ be the point from which the tangents are drawn. (I’m using $\theta$ instead of $\alpha$ to avoid confusion in the formulas below.) Using the result from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2313152/265466) or via the method described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/867428/265466) for finding the intersection of the ellipse and the polar line to $P$ we have the following points at which the tangents through $P$ intersect the ellipse $$\left({a^2\left(b^2\cos\theta\mp\sin\theta\sqrt{L^2b^2\cos^2\theta+L^2a^2\sin^2\theta-a^2b^2}\right) \over L(b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta)},{b^2\left(a^2\sin^2\theta\pm\cos\theta\sqrt{L^2b^2\cos^2\theta+L^2a^2\sin^2\theta-a^2b^2}\right) \over L(b^2\cos^2\theta+a^2\sin^2\theta)}\right)$$ The first of these points in the one in the upper half-plane when $\theta=0$, as per your diagram. Using that tangent point, we have $$\tan\beta=-{b^2\left(a^2\sin^2\theta+\cos\theta\sqrt{L^2b^2\cos^2\theta+L^2a^2\sin^2\theta-a^2b^2}\right) \over a^2\left(b^2\cos\theta-\sin\theta\sqrt{L^2b^2\cos^2\theta+L^2a^2\sin^2\theta-a^2b^2}\right)}.$$