# Construct a pole to a given line for a conic in a simple way

Tags: conic-sections, projective-geometry, geometric-construction

**Pole -> Polar**

It is easy to construct a polar to a given point *P* like this:

[image]

Draw 2 arbitrary lines *AB* and *CD* through *P* then get *R*=*AC*∩*BD* and *Q*=*AD*∩*BC*, then *QR* is the polar of *P*.

So we can only draw 7 lines to get the polar.

**Polar -> Pole**

But the inverse looks more complicated:

To get the pole *P* to a line *QR*, the only way I can find is:

- draw the polar *ST* for any point *Q* on the given line (draw 7 lines)
- draw the polar *UV* for any point *R* on the given line (draw 7 lines, 4 lines if share 3 lines with previous)
- *P*=*ST*∩*UV*

Then we need to draw at least 11 lines to find a pole to a line.

Are there simpler ways to do this?

Comment: Is a compass allowed?

Comment: Yes I think. But I don't think compass useful in this case. Can you finish it within 10 lines + arcs/circles (if compass used) ?

Comment: Agreed, if you count arcs/circles you're not much ahead..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempted explanation for why there are extra steps.  The short version is that even though projective geometry has a duality principle, the game of straightedge construction is rigged against one side of the duality.

For the polar->pole construction, let's dualize the construction you gave for pole->polar.

[image]

Starting with the conic and line $p$, select points $D,E$ on $p$ and draw tangents to the conic.  Find the four intersections of the four tangents - $F,G,H,I$.  Then the pole $P$ is the intersection of $FG\cap HI$.  Voila, we've drawn seven lines to get the pole.

But, you object, we can't just pull the four tangents out of a hat.  They have to be constructed using the polars of $D$ and $E$, at a cost of several more lines.

The counter argument to this is that in the pole->polar construction, we're assuming that the conic has been drawn explicitly and accurately. Maybe that's a bad assumption, and we need to construct the intersection points explicitly, based on the five points defining the conic, as in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4136001/1257).  That would make for a much longer construction.

In a world of perfect duality, drawing a tangent to a conic from a point should be just as easy as intersecting a line and a conic.  Drawing a tangent from a point could be considered as selecting a line from a line conic, which is dual to selecting a point on a point conic.

This is true in, say, Geogebra, where constructing a tangent is a primitive, on the same level as finding an intersection.  But in the world of straight edge and paper the rules work against this equivalence.  We take for granted that we can draw a line through a conic and pick out the intersections, but we don't accept that we can do the dual task of finding a tangent from a point in a single step.

The deal breaker is that in straightedge constructions we think of the point conic locus as a given, while that's not true of the line conic, because it is impossible to draw and work with the lines which form the envelope.