# Calculate intersection points of a circle and an ellipse

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations, quadratics, conic-sections

I have a circle and an ellipse with the following general equations:

\begin{align*}
Circle: (x - m)^2 + (y - n)^2 &= r^2 \\\
Ellipse: \frac{(x - o)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y - p)^2}{b^2} &= 1
\end{align*}

Where $(x, y)$ are coordinates for the intersection point(s), $(m, n)$ is the center of the circle, $r$ is the circle's radius, $(o, p)$ is the center of the ellipse, $a$ is major radius and $b$ is minor radius. The ellipse has inclination of $0^\circ$.

Obviously I know every value except $(x, y)$ so I can opt for a numerical solution but that's not what I need.

I know that there are 6 cases for the solution depending on the number of intersection points:

- no points
- 1 (sharing a tangent line)
- 2
- 3 (one point sharing a tangent line)
- 4
- infinitely many (if centers and radii are the same)

I've looked at other questions but they are using other equations like [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197982/714869) or are asking for the area of the intersection like [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1688449/714869).

If you cannot provide the equations, at least some pointers on how to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Please also refer to comments from another post [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4348451).

Comment: Do you want to classify all the possible solutions? Is that a useful thing to do?

Comment: $3$ common points are also possible, one of them being a point of tangency.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean? I need to know how many solutions there are in the real 2D plane and what their coordinates are. The complex solutions are not interesting to me.

Comment: The system of two given equations leads to two functions
$$x=f_1(a,b,m,n,r,o,p)\\y=f_2(a,b,m,n,r,o,p)$$ and all statement about the intersection points is coming from these two functions (the form of these functions is certainly not rational).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Comment: As shown in picture for each point of intersection, we must have a system of two equations of first degree $C(x.y)=c$ which represent the circle and $E(x, y)=e $ which represents the ellipse. These equations are resulting from factorization of equations of circle and ellipse to first degree factors. Suppose we get :

$Circle: C(x, y)=c_1\cdot c_2$

and from ellipse:

$Ellipse: E(x, y))=e_1\cdot e_2$

then we have to search for solution of following system of equations of first degree:

$\begin{cases}C(x, y)=c_1\\E(x, y)=e_1\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}C(x, y)=c_1\\E(x, y)=e_2\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}C(x, y)=c_2\\E(x, y)=e_1\end{cases}$

$\begin{cases}C(x, y)=c_2\\E(x, y)=e_2\end{cases}$

which give the coordinates of points E, F, G and B, in case they intersect. You may find one, two, three or four solutions or nothing at all(when all systems are inconsistent).

Note:

A similar question I answered long ago but I could not find it. You can also that if you find.

Comment: The _op_ does not assume the ellipse and circle share a center.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou, This comment was just to show a method. When I say you may find no solution it also means they may have no common center.