# Elementary trigonometric simplification (regarding intersection of two hyperbolas)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I am trying to find the points where two hyperbolas intersect; where one hyperbola, $H1$, is a hyperbola centered at $(0,0)$ and lying horizontal:
$$\frac{x^2}{a_1^2} - \frac{y^2}{b_1^2} = 1\tag 1$$
and $H2$ is a hyperbola rotated to $\theta$ and centered at $(h, k)$:
$$\frac{[(y-k)\sin\theta - (x-h)\cos\theta]^2}{a_2^2} - \frac{[(y-k)\cos\theta - (x-h)\sin\theta]^2}{b_2^2} = 1\tag 2$$

After solving (1) for $y$ and substituting that into (2), it took a ton of manipulations but I was able to  eventually get it into the form of:

$$\alpha_4x^4 + \alpha_3x^3 + \alpha_2x^2 + \alpha_1x + \alpha_0 = 0$$

where:

$$\alpha_4 =(A^2-B^2F)$$
$$\alpha_3 = (2AC - 2BDF)$$
$$\alpha_2 = (C^2 - 2AE - D^2F + B^2G)$$
$$\alpha_1 = (2BDG - 2CE)$$
$$\alpha_0 =E^2 + D^2G$$

and

$$\left[ \frac{b_1^2b_2^2\sin^2\theta}{a_1^2} -\frac{b_1^2a_2^2\cos^2\theta}{a_1^2} + b_2^2\cos^2\theta - a_2^2\sin^2\theta \right]\tag A$$

$$\left[2a_2^2\sin\theta\cos\theta - 2b_2^2\sin\theta\cos\theta \right] \tag B$$

$$\left[2a_2^2j\sin\theta - 2b_2^2i\cos\theta \right]\tag C$$

$$\left[2b_2^2i\sin\theta - 2a_2^2j\cos\theta \right]\tag D$$

$$\left[ a_2^2 b_2^2 - b_2^2i^2  - b_1^2a_2^2\cos^2\theta + b_1^2b_2^2\sin^2\theta  + a_2^2j^2\right]\tag E$$

$$\frac{b_1^2}{a_1^2}\tag F$$

$$b_1^2\tag G$$

and

$$h\sin\theta - k\cos\theta\tag j$$

$$h\cos\theta-k\sin\theta\tag i$$

where $\theta, a_1, a_2, b_1, b_2, h,$ and $k$ are all known constants.

At this point my brain hurts, and I am awful at trigonometric substitutions, but it seems like there is an opportunity to simplify each of the $\alpha$ coefficients.   For example, B looks like it contains the double angle, $\sin(2\theta)$, but it's not obvious to a non-mathematician like me that it helps simplify this beast.

**In order to get to the general equation I am seeking I need help simplifying any and all of the $\alpha$ coefficients, if possible.**

-Or- if there is a book or link to some site that will give me the equation(s) for the x values of the (up to) four points that would be even better -- I will gladly throw my work in the dumpster.  It seems to me this was likely solved in antiquity, but I couldn't find a solution with Google.

Note: I have put all my work to get to the polynomial in LaTeX form but it is so long winded I didn't want to include it.   I am happy to do so if it helps or if there is concern I screwed it up.

Comment: Is your goal to end up with a formula for the up to four intersection points?

Comment: Eventually, yes.

Comment: As you suspect, simplifying these coefficients isn’t going to help much, since there’s no nice formula for the roots of a quartic. There is an algorithm for finding the intersections of any two specific conics that might be useful to you, though, since it can be completely automated.

Comment: I was hoping if it simplifies nicely (probably not), to see if it fits any of the special cases around factoring quartics (probably not).  But can you supply a name and/or link to the algorithm you are talking about?

Comment: Seems unlikely that the general case will factor nicely. I can construct an example of each of the possible numbers of intersections.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425412/265466) outlines the intersection algorithm, with references to more details. The idea in the other answer to that question might be interesting to explore, too: scale to transform the first hyperbola into the right hyperbola $X^2-Y^2=1$

Comment: Ah that is interesting.   I did transform it to a standard horizontal one centered about (0,0) but didn't go with a right hyperbola (just yet).   I see some tweaks I can make to the beast up above to make it a bit better to work with (let $F = \frac{b_1}{a_1}$ and do the same with G ... makes them much easier to work with and simplifies the coefficients a little).

Comment: It does feel like, with all the redundancy hidden in the coefficients, that there is a possibility of special cases applying.   But I have nothing but gut feel about it for now.