# Intersection of a hyperbola and a circle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

Suppose that we have algebraic equations for a circle and a hyperbola given by
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$
$$Ax^2 + 2Bxy - Ay^2 + Cx + Dy = 0$$ respectively. The real coefficients $A,B,C,D$ have a negative discriminant $\Delta = -(A^2 + B^2)$. These two curves intersect due to the origin being a root to the hyperbola equation, which can be viewed as an unbounded function in the $xy$-plane.

Does there exist algebraic geometric methods for finding the intersection points? I have little knowledge of the subject but if there are methods for specifying the intersection points of these simple curves I would like to know. I know that substitution leads to a fourth order polynomial but solution by radicals leads to complicated formula which seem intractable. I am interested in finding these intersection points as they correspond to equilibrium points of a system of differential equations. I am curious if anyone knows a change of coordinates that make finding these intersections a little more tractable.

Comment: You can find a general recipe for intersecting two conics [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425412/265466). It entails finding a degenerate linear combination of them (which involves solving a cubic), splitting them into their component lines, and then intersecting those lines with one of the original conics.

Comment: For this case in particular, you could instead find a parameterization of the hyperbola and then solve for values of the parameter for which the distance to the origin is $1$.

Comment: @TheRefrigerator Is there an answer you like here? If you do, please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of @Peter Foreman's answer, you can rewrite the second equation as $$\dfrac{2bx+d\pm\sqrt{4b^2x^2+4bdx+d^2+4a^2x^2+4acx}}{2a}=y$$. Then, rewrite the first equation as $$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ Make the two equations equal to each other and solve.

Answer (score 0):

Write $y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and use this definition in the second equation. This problem then becomes solving a quartic for which there is a quartic formula.

Comment: It is $$y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}$$

Comment: Yes, sorry it is.

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer you are looking for, and probably not the forum for it, but you can plot the two curves using software, for example *Mathematica* or MATLAB or Python or Java or ...

Here is a quick way to do it in *Mathematica*, for example:

```
 a[x_, y_] := (x^2 + y^2 - 1);
 b[x_, y_][A_, B_, C_, D_] := (A x^2 + 2 B x y - A y^2 + C x + D y );
 c = 3;
 Manipulate[
    Show[ContourPlot[{a[x, y], b[x, y][A, B, C, D]}, {x, -c, c}, {y, -c, c}],
      Graphics[{Red, PointSize -> Large, Point[{0, 0}]}]], 
        {A, -2, 2}, {B, -2, 2}, {C, -2, 2}, {D, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

You can also explicitly ask for the solutions:

```
With[{A = 1.15, B = -1.29, C = 1.95, D = 0}, 
  NSolve[{a[x, y] == 0, b[x, y][A, B, C, D] == 0}]]
```

This returns:

```
{{x -> 0.689595, y -> 0.724195}, {x -> 0.230435, y -> -0.973088}, 
 {x -> -0.871638, y -> 0.490151}, {x -> -0.799246, y -> 0.601004}}
```