# Area of Intersection of Two Ellipses

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given two ellipses in space where:

- a & c are major diameters
- b & d are minor diameters
- h & k are x-axis centers
- j & i are y-axis centers
- r & s are the rotation of each ellipse

[Equation - Ellipse 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwupU.jpg)

[Equation - Ellipse 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KKnT.jpg)

[Graph of Ellipses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m18MJ.jpg)

How do I determine if the two ellipses touch?  And what the area of overlap is?

We have been solving this using cad programs for years, but the time to solution for multiple cases is a burden.

Comment: Uh, how good are you at solving 4th degree equations?

Comment: See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.3787).

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/425366/35416) for finding points of intersection. Could then cut along the secant and transform each ellipse segment to unit circle to compute area there, then correct for the transformation.